# App version compare with different version format

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need some help regarding a small bit of code which needs some expert advice. It is a code I wrote on my own for comparing versions of an application with that of app store version. It has some small flaw but I couldn't move forward with it. Any help will be greatly valuable.

```
function versionCompare(appVersionInStore, appVersionInReq) {
  var versionStoreArray = appVersionInStore.split('.');
  var versionReqArray = appVersionInReq.split('.');
  var arrIndex;
  var len = Math.max(versionStoreArray.length, versionReqArray.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < versionStoreArray.length; i++) {
    if (versionStoreArray[i].length < 2) {
      versionStoreArray[i] = '0' + versionStoreArray[i];
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < versionReqArray.length; i++) {
    if (versionReqArray[i].length < 2) {
      versionReqArray[i] = '0' + versionReqArray[i];
    }
  }
  appVersionInStore = versionStoreArray.join('');
  appVersionInReq = versionReqArray.join('');
  appVersionInStore = parseInt(appVersionInStore);
  appVersionInReq = parseInt(appVersionInReq);
  var result = appVersionInStore - appVersionInReq;
  return result;
}


var versionDifference = versionCompare('3.1.2', '3.1.7');
  if (versionDifference >= 4) {
    appUpdatePolicy = 'MANDATORY';
  } else if ((versionDifference >= 1) && (versionDifference <= 3)) {
    appUpdatePolicy = 'OPTIONAL';
  } else if ((versionDifference <= 0)) {
    appUpdatePolicy = 'NONE';
  }

 return appUpdatePolicy;
```

This is returning appUpdatePolicy with three values - MNADATORY, OPTIONAL, OR NONE based on the versionCompare() function. Now if the version are in similar format(3.1.1 - 2 decimal or 17.2 - 1 decimal) and are being compared, its working fine. If they are not in similar format (3.1.2 being compared with 17.2), it's not working fine. Any helps on this?

We have a use case where in the version can be in different format possibly.

Comment: What should `versionCompare` output? For example, what should `versionCompare('1.2.3', '3.2.1')` return?

Comment: -19998.. So it will return a NONE -  appUpdatePolicy